# Is there something called method to proc just like symbol to proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
> %w(action_controller/railtie action_mailer/railtie).map &method(:require)
 => [true, true]
```

And method call returns an instance of Method.

```
> method(:require)
 => #<Method: Object(Kernel)#require>
```

So there has to be a to_proc definition in method and it should be something like

```
class Method
  def to_proc
    proc { |obj| self.send(obj) }
  end
end
```

My question is does rails override this to_proc in Method or what.

why following command is behaving the way it is behaving

```
> %w(action_controller/railtie action_mailer/railtie).map &method(:require)
 => [true, true]
```

Comment: If there is a question in there, I cannot see it. That method does exists, so what's your question? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-to_proc

Comment: Updated my question to reflect what I am asking. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`method#to_proc` returns something that, when you call `call` on it, the method, passing the supplied arguments. For example

```
method(:puts).call("hello world")
```

outputs hello world. That method "remembers" where it came from, in this case your script's top level object. Methods like `puts`,`require` are define (via Kernel) on Object, so it doesn't really matter what object the method is bound to (assuming of course that class doesn't define its own require method!)

So `%w(action_controller/railtie action_mailer/railtie).map &method(:require)` is equivalent to calling require passing in those strings one at a time and collecting the return value(which happens to be `true` - don't pay too much attention to the return value of require.

This is not a rails thing - you could do exactly the same thing in a vanilla irb session with any files available to be required. I'm not I would do this - it strikes me as choosing 'cute' over 'understandable'.